# Whait does Pyspark rdd command do?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm just getting started with pyspark and I have a question (maybe it's too easy but I can't see it)
I have a dataframe of animal species with columns: 'category', 'name' and 'status'
and I'm using this command to obtain some info on the category columns:

```
df.groupBy('category').count().show()
```

yielding:

```
+-----------------+-----+
|         category|count|
+-----------------+-----+
|   Vascular Plant| 4470|
|             Bird|  521|
|           Mammal|  214|
|        Amphibian|   80|
|Nonvascular Plant|  333|
|             Fish|  127|
|          Reptile|   79|
+-----------------+-----+
```

then I used this line:

```
df.select('category').rdd.countByValue()
```

and got this:

```
defaultdict(int,
        {Row(category='Bird'): 521,
         Row(category='Reptile'): 79,
         Row(category='Fish'): 127,
         Row(category='Vascular Plant'): 4470,
         Row(category='Nonvascular Plant'): 333,
         Row(category='Amphibian'): 80,
         Row(category='Mammal'): 214})
```

So my question is: what does the 'rdd' part add to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD is the  logical representation of dataset in spark. It is stored across multiple machines could be servers too in case of a cluster. These are immutable and can be recovered in case of a failure.

A dataset is a data externally loaded by the user. Could come from any source be it a database a simple text file.

Please refer the following link:

[Spark Notes](https://github.com/linbojin/spark-notes/blob/master/research-papers/Resilient%20Distributed%20Datasets%20A%20Fault%20Tolerant%20Abstraction%20for%20In-Memory%20Cluster%20Computing.pdf)

Comment: ok, so by adding 'rdd' I'm 'saving' the resulting set of information in the multiple machine system that I'm working with. am I correct?

Comment: Reference of that values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433027/what-is-rdd-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're converting the spark dataframe into an rdd object by invoking the `.rdd` method. This is why you get a defaultdict back ([a subclass of dict](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-defaultdict/)) instead of a table.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000514/how-to-convert-a-dataframe-back-to-normal-rdd-in-pyspark) for more details on the function doing the converting.